# Create new row every n items on angular4

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript

How can I create a new bootstrap row every n items ? I tried `*ngIf="idx % 2 === 0; else templateWithoutRow` but obviously it's not working.
Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like that but this is not really nice:

```
<div *ngFor="let row of items; let i = index">
  <div *ngIf=" i % 4 === 0 " class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let item of items.slice(i,i+4)"> 
       {{item}}  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I haven't verified the work of the code.